# When making a subclass of NSObject, what is the purpose of adding <NSCoding> afterwards?

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between

```
@interface RWTItem : NSObject <NSCoding>
```

and

```
@interface RWTItem : NSObject
```

What does the `<NSCoding>` part do?

Comment: So you can read docs on NSCoding

Answer (score 0):

NSCoding is a simple protocol, with two methods: -initWithCoder: and encodeWithCoder:. Classes that conform to NSCoding can be serialized and deserialized into data that can be either be archived to disk or distributed across a network. Good [tutorial](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) and [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data). If put it simply NSCoding indicates that the object can be serialized. (compressed)